# Leaves seem burnt

Tags: vegetables, leaves

I have some basil plants and a tomato plant (which is hanging upside down and growing well) however their leaves seem to be burned. I live in Florida and they are out on my balcony but I'm not too sure what to do for them is that ends up being the problem.

Comment: Could you post some pictures please? If you link them from an outside host we can upload them to the SE image host and integrate them into the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most likely cause is that they are not getting enough water. You should be watering your plants every day, especially if they are getting a lot of sun.

Moreover, depending on the size of your container, the sun can really heat up smaller containers and create an oven-like effect on your plants, causing extreme heat and rapid evaporation that damages/dries up the roots. You may consider a bigger container in the future. I'm not sure it would be wise to transplant them at this point, but I'm betting your soil is getting really hot. You may consider watering in the heat of the day to cool the soil so as to give the roots a break.

Also, although less likely, you may have over-fertilized your plants. I don't think this is the case since you did not mention fertilizing them recently, but I am throwing that out there since burnt leaves can be a result of over-fertilization.